# Generating raw_inputs based on user input? [Python]

Tags: python, raw-input

Is there any way to generate a number of raw_inputs (With unique variables) based on user input? So, say I had this:

```
if choice == 1:
    noelemen = int(raw_input("Enter total amount of elements: "))
```

Would there be any way to make it so the integer put in that raw_input field would then "generate" the required amount of raw_inputs? I'd suppose, if it was possible, that it'd make use of functions or something similar, but I'm a bit confused about how I'd get it done to be able to do that.

What I have currently is this:

```
if noelemen == 1:
        first = raw_input("Enter element: ")

        #Look for the weight of the entered element
        weight1 = float(elemen_data.get(first.lower()))

        if weight1 is not None:
            total_weight = weight1
        print "Total mass =", total_weight

if  noelemen == 2:
        first = raw_input("Enter first element: ")
        second = raw_input("Enter second element: ")

        #Look for the weight of the entered element
        weight1 = float(elemen_data.get(first.lower()))
        weight2 = float(elemen_data.get(second.lower()))

        if weight1 is not None:
            total_weight = weight1 + weight2
        print "Total mass =", total_weight
```

Which is probably a pretty messy way of doing it, particularly as I'd have to go up to perhaps something like 10 elements, or perhaps even beyond.

So, to repeat... Any way to generate raw_inputs with unique variables based on user input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

how about something like this?

```
elements = []
numberOfPrompts = raw_input("Enter total amount of elements: ")
for i in range(numberOfPrompts):
   # will prompt "Enter Element 1: " on the first iteration
   userInput = raw_input("Enter Element %s" % (i+1, )) 
   elements.append(userInput)
```

### Example case:

```
>>> Enter total amount of elements: 2 # now hit enter
```

at this point, the value of the variable `numberOfPrompts` will be `2`.
The value of the variable `elements` will be `[]`, i.e. it is an empty list

```
>>> Enter Element 1: 3.1415 # hit enter
```

`numberOfPrompts` stays `2`,
`elements` will be `['3.1415']`

```
>>> Enter Element 2: 2.7182
```

`elements` will be `['3.1415', '2.7182']`

Now the for-loop is done and you got your user inputs conveniently in the 0-indexed list `elements`, which you access like a tuple (*array*):

```
>>> elements[1]
2.7182
```

---

### Edit:

After reading your comment I noticed what you intend to do and, just like the other answer stated, it would be best to use a dictionary for this. This should work:

```
elements = {}
numberOfPrompts = raw_input("Enter total amount of elements: ")
for i in range(numberOfPrompts):
   # will prompt "Enter Element 1: " on the first iteration
   userInput = raw_input("Enter Element %s" % (i+1, )) 
   userInput = userInput.lower()
   elements[userInput] = float(elem_data.get(userInput))
```

now `elements` will look like this:

```
{'oxygen':15.9994, 'hydrogen':1.0079}
```

you can iterate over all keys like this (to find out, which elements have been entered):

```
for element in elements.keys():
    print element
# output:
oxygen
hydrogen
```

To get all values (to sum them up, for instance), do something like this:

```
weightSum = 0
for weight in elements.values():
    weightSum += weight
print weightSum
# output:
17,0073
```

Keep in mind that this example is for python 2.x. For python 3.x you will need to adjust a couple of things.

Comment: Wait, does this assign a unique variable to each raw_input generated? Currently it just seems to overwrite each previously entered element... Might just be doing something wrong with my lookup, though.

Comment: You will have a list `elements`, which has `numberOfPrompts` elements in it, in order.

Comment: My only problem is that setting it out like this: http://i.imgur.com/HHYEP.png (Which is the only way that actually prints a value) ends up only giving the weight of the last element entered. The others throw up various errors like AttributeErrors and such.

Comment: I think we're on different pages, then. I have a CSV file that I'm importing element names and element weights from, so that when you type, for example, Oxygen, it'll search the CSV for it and return 15.9994 (Precise, I know). If you type in Oxygen in one field, then Hydrogen in the next, it'll take those two, look up the weights, then add them together. That kind of thing.

Comment: `userInput` holds an integer. Calling `.lower()` on it will cause python to throw an error since there is no (built-in) method called `.lower()` on that object. It worked in your previous code since you were reading the user input directly from the console with `raw_input`, which returns a string to you. Check out my extended answer to understand how you can get your values.

Comment: reading your last comment i now see what you need. I will adjust my answer.

Comment: T'would be very much appreciated! :)

Comment: Works now! Just needed to add the "userInput.lower" part into the lookup instead of having it by itself. Only problem is that it prints the total weight x times, where x = the amount of elements. But I'm fairly sure I can fix that somehow. Thanks for all the help! EDIT: Just fixed that. Everything works perfectly now.

Comment: You are welcome! Oh and, `userInput.lower()` indeed was wrong by itself, since it just returns the string in lowercase but leaves `userInput` as it is. This would be correct: `userInput = userInput.lower()`. I have (yet again) adjusted my answer accordingly. :)

Comment: Nah, I entered it into here: elements[userInput] = float(elemen_data.get(userInput.lower())) It's the way I did it before, and it seems to make this way work too while taking out a line of code.

Comment: Keep in mind though that your dictionary might look like `{"OxyGEN":15.9994, ...}` (random casing) but `elemen_data.get` searches for "oxygen" (all lowercase). If you don't use the dictionary keys for anything else than that, everything should be fine.

Comment: I can enter either "Oxygen" or "oxygen" and it works fine. Keeping to that shouldn't be too hard for anyone using it, I hope. I'd add some error correction, but that'd be a ten ton of work for comparatively little benefit.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a dictionary for this:

```
noelemen = int(raw_input("Enter total amount of elements: "))
elem={}
for x in xrange(1,noelemen+1):
    elem[x]=raw_input("Enter element: ")
```

Comment: IMO, the problem calls out for a list, not a dict with integer keys.